# why undefined [object Object],[object Object] on react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an arry :

```
classesAll:[0:{id:1,title:'test1'},1:{id:2,title:'test2'}]
```

It dosent return the excepted value of my array when I 'console.log(this.props.classes.classesAll)' it to console. Instead it shows the following : undefined [object Object],[object Object]

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.showAllClasses();
    console.log("***", this.props.classes.classesAll)
  }
Redux action:

export const showAllClasses = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
       dispatch(pageLoading(true));
            await  Api.get(`classes.php`).then(res => {
                //this.state.all = res.data;
                const classesAll = res.data.data;
                state.classesAll = classesAll;
            });
       await dispatch(onChangeClasessAll(state.classesAll));
       dispatch(pageLoading(false));
        };

    };

    export const onChangeClasessAll = classesAll => {
        const type =  CLASSES_ALL;
         return   { type , classesAll};
      };
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApFX2.jpg)

Comment: From the console output it looks like you're logging `{ type, classesAll }`, where `type` is `undefined` and the elements of `classesAll` are being turned into strings. Have never used Redux so can't comment further but maybe it helps.

Comment: what does console.log(res.data[0]) show after your Api.get call

Comment: what kind of array is this `[0:{id:1,title:'test1'},1:{id:2,title:'test2'}]`? this should throw an error.

Comment: @Mike - console.log(res.data[0]); show undefined , but  console.log(res.data)  show the data in the array

Answer (score 0):

Because your request is async. you should console it when the request is returned. in react-native 0.6, you can do it in the getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) method

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    console.log(props.classes.classesAll)
}
```

before the react-native 0.6, you should do it in the componentWillReceiveProps() method

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 console.log(props.classes.classesAll)
}
```

Comment: Shows me again  : undefined [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @Ranaa do you map the props to redux state?

Answer (score 0):

Please improve your action and make sure you are getting the res.data from server.

```
export const showAllClasses = () => dispatch => {
   dispatch(pageLoading(true));
   const res = await Api.get(`classes.php`);
   dispatch(onChangeClasessAll(res.data));
   dispatch(pageLoading(false));
};
```

Then console the this.props in render method just like

```
render(){
  console.log(this.props);
  return
    ......
}
```

You will see all the props in the console so you can easily get the data from there.

Comment: Api.get can get the data from the server, my action is working properly but i cant access it in commpoent. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApFX2.jpg)

Comment: did you use connect?

Comment: yes, I use connect.                                                                                               
 export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Classes);

Comment: Also share the response which you are getting from server

Comment: Plese see :  https://pastebin.com/eEmn1Aw2       my componenet

Comment: Please send me your redux code as well what is name of this reducer.